# flot - Is it possible to recreate a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I've been trying to recreate a selection from the output it generates (and placed into a textbox called #spectrum_selection)

```
$('#spectrum').bind('plotselected', function(event, ranges) {
        $('#spectrum_selection').val(ranges.xaxis.from.toFixed(1) + ',' + ranges.xaxis.to.toFixed(1));

        if ($('#zoom').attr('checked'))
        {
            $.plot($('#spectrum'), data,
            $.extend(true, {}, options, {
                xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to }
            }));
        }
    });
```

I use split(',') to break the xaxis ranges. However, I couldn't find a way to recreate the selection from the ranges. Is there are tucked away function that would allow this?

Thank you very much for any help =)

Comment: Yay! found it:$('#spectrum').setSelection({ xaxis: { from: 0, to: 3 } });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay! found it:$('#spectrum').setSelection({ xaxis: { from: 0, to: 3 } });